# Onclicking an inner div also onclicks the outer div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an outer div called `paragraph` and two inner divs called `word`. I also have a custom audio playing function in JS that I got from another SO post:

```
<div class="paragraph" onclick="playSound('this, paragraph.mp3');">
    <div class="word" onclick="playSound('this, word1.mp3');">Word1</div>
    <div class="word" onclick="playSound('this, word2.mp3');">Word2</div>
</div>


function playSound(el,soundfile) {
    if (el.mp3) {
        if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
        else el.mp3.pause();
    } else {
        el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
        el.mp3.play();
    }
}
```

When I click the paragraph div, it plays the `paragraph.mp3` perfectly. However when I click one of the word divs inside, it simultaneously plays both `paragraph.mp3` and `word.mp3`. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the event bubbling by adding these lines of code to your playsound function

```js
const e = window.event;
 
e.cancelBubble = true;

if (e.stopPropagation) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

This will stop JavaScript's event bubbling and propagation

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked! However when I used your exact code it tells me "`ReferenceError: e is not defined`" error and when I removed the `if (!e)` part, it worked perfectly. Is that part necessary?

Comment: I actually updated that because I thought you were passing in the event as well. so yeah you're good :)

Answer (score 7):

If you use addEventListener() instead of inline onclick, you can call stopPropagation() on the event object passed to it to prevent the event from bubbling up.

```
word1Div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    playSound(this, 'word1.mp3');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the issue is, I have hundreds of words in a paragraph all with different audio links. So do I have to add this code for every word or is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: You could use querySelectorAll() or getElementsByClassName() to select all your word elements and add event listeners in a loop (or with the forEach() method).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a **simpler** approach for a similar problem with embedded ★ links in my CSS buttons. I set global variable *embedDiv* to TRUE preceding my inner onClick function. In the outer onClick function, I skipped code if *embedDIV* was true and reset *embedDiv* to FALSE.

```
<script>
var embedDiv = false;

function tm(wikiPlace) { 
      if(!embedDiv) { place(wikiPlace); alert("( " + wikiPlace + " ) -- " + tym); } 
      embedDiv = false;
}
</script>

<div onclick="tm('Argentina')">Argentina<span 
     onclick="embedDiv=true;go('Argentina')">&starf;</span></div>
```

[image: Time Zones - other buttons]

[Time-Place-Pronounce](https://xradio.us/start/time-place-pronounce.html)